# Update chrome extension manifest permissions from options page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to update the permissions in the chrome extension manifest file from the options page. 
Basically the user should be able to input the url for the extension to run on and that url will update in the extensions manifest file.
I am currently storing all my options using chrome.storage.sync for use in multiple files.
I am looking for a secure solution to give only the chosen url access. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to change permissions, or to change content scripts? If the latter, do you have specific restrictions on `run_at`?

Comment: I will need to do both eventually but I was trying to solve one problem at a time and hoping one would lead to the other. I don't believe I have any restrictions on `run_at` currently.

Comment: Do you need `externally_connectable` as well? In general, please explain what your extension is supposed to do.

Comment: (I'm asking this because updating the manifest is impossible, but it's possible to approximate some of it)

Comment: The extension gathers a string from an input box on the webpage and then passes it to an app via messaging. This occurs when the extension icon is clicked. The app passes back a string that is is displayed in a text box on the webpage.

Comment: And the specific reason you want to avoid just blanket permissions-for-everything? In which sense would a certain way to do it "secure"?

Comment: The data is used for payment processing so I am trying to limit access.

Comment: I do not understand your threat model. The browser's user can inspect everything you do. Other extensions can't interfere outside the page's DOM.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible (to update the manifest).

However, the particular use case you explain is:

1. Have a list of "allowed" websites.
2. When the extension is invoked by pressing the button, if the website is allowed - inject a content script that does something.

In this case [`"activeTab"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) and [Programmatic Injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) should solve your problem.

- You do not declare any content scripts in the manifest. This ensures code runs only when you want to.
- You do not declare any host permissions in the manifest. Your extension will ONLY work on the current tab at the moment of Browser Action press.
- You ask the user for allowed URLs and store them in `chrome.storage`.
- When your extension is invoked using the Browser Action, you can query the currently active tab and you will get its URL (because of the `"activeTab"` permission).

  - Your logic then compares it to stored whitelisted URLs.
  - If there's a match - you use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to inject your content script.
  - If there's no match - do nothing, or somehow ask user to confirm whitelisting the new domain.

Here's some sample code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  var currentTab = tabs[0];
  // Pseudocode
  if (whitelisted(currentTab.url)) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(currentTab.id, {file: "content.js"});
  } else {
    // Do nothing or show some warning
  }
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can look at [Optional Permissions API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).